# iOS autolayout: set constraints in viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, constraints

I have a `view controller` with xib. xib contains all the subviews without constraints and I need to add these constraints manually. Everything is correct when I write my code in `viewDidLoad`. But I need to get a size parameter which is available in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` only. When I try to call my code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` then I get the following error:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79edebb0 V:|-(50)-[UILabel:0x79f11bf0'You haven't imported any ...']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79f11940 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79e4b190 V:|-(49)-[UILabel:0x79f11bf0'You haven't imported any ...']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79f11940 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79edebb0 V:|-(50)-[UILabel:0x79f11bf0'You haven't imported any ...']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79f11940 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

The constraints are simple: all the views are placed in one column, fixed width, fixed height, distance between topmost view and superview's top border, distances between neighbour views and finally all the views are snapped to the superview's horizontal center.

**UPDATED**

I found the reason of the problem but I don't know why it doesn't work.

The problem is the topmost constraint value was based on views' **bounds**. The height value inside this `bounds` structure "jumps" by 1 (because `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called multiple times). But why does it cause problems with constraints?

Comment: The code you've added to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` would be very useful to see

Comment: Adding constraints in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is a bit of a code smell. There is probably a better way to achieve the same results.

Answer (score 0):

it says that 1 of the UILabel have Constraint which breaks layout. 
2 options

1. clear Constraint of all label and set Constraint of each label by try n error
2. set id to all constraint of uilabel and then u will see id of constraint in

warning or error output.

basically it is due to u added an unwanted constraint.